# Custom login page with Django 1.11

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-1.11

I looked for an already existing answer but I didn't find one. For a school project I have to create a website with Django 1.11.

My problem here is the following: I have to create the login page. Using Django class based view (login view in this example) but I dind't find any example. How to use a custom login page (not form.asp) (something like that) and connect it with my view and model ?